# Can i create a SPA using jquery and javascript and Asp.NET MVC and without thirdparty js framework?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application

I want to create a Asp.NET MVC SPA application using .net , jquery, javascript. These technology stack is fine to create a SPA application or i must use knockout or ember or angular in my SPA Application?

Comment: Although possible this is a bad idea. The frameworks exist and are used routinely because it allows you to focus on building your application. Rather than rebuilding all the backend systems and services that are provided by large organisations and teams who's sole purpose to exist, is to do this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For SPA, you should choose a JavaScript framework such as Angular, Aurelia or any other. If you use jQuery, you can still create a SPA but it requires a lot of plumbing. Also, its harder to maintain application state using jQuery.

Comment: So it is not possible to create SPA , just using Asp.Net MVC & Jquery/Javascript. We need some third party framework like angular or knockout.js?

Comment: Its possible to create a SPA just using Asp.Net MVC & Jquery/Javascript but you will face a very high difficulty level You need to manually handle the application state, routing and maintaining the browser history is very cumbersome. Using a javascript framework will reduce this difficulty level to very low. You can focus more on your business logic rather than creating a SPA framework with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is possible to make single page application in asp.net core without using any third party javascript framework.

Check this nuget Package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxSpaMvcCore/ 

Github Repository : https://github.com/KishorNaik/Sol_Ajax_Spa_MVC_Core